# Symfony2 frequently losing login

Tags: php, symfony, session, authentication

I have a Symfony2 based project, coded authentication myself (based on the documentation and cookbook). The project has 2 type of users: some are authenticated with LDAP, the others with database credentials.
The problem is if there are more users logged in their session is lost frequently (after 5 minutes or less) and they need to login again (currently I am in dev environment). 
Is there something I could've done wrong (I don't think so though) or is this a Symfony2 bug or PHP settings are causing this?
Any help is deeply appreciated.

The listener:

```
class LdapListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    protected $tokenStorage;
    protected $authenticationManager;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authenticationManager = $authenticationManager;
    }

    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $username = $request->request->get('_username');
        $password = $request->request->get('_password');

        if ($username == null OR $password == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        $token = new LdapUserToken();
        $token->setUser($username);
        $token->setPassword($password);

        try
        {
            $authenticationToken = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);
            $this->tokenStorage->setToken($authenticationToken);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException $exception)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Denied');
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

The authentication provider:

```
class LdapProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface {

    private $userProvider;
    private $em;

    const ENC_KEY = 'SECRETKEY';

    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $doctrine) {
        $this->em           = $doctrine->getManager();
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token) {
        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());

        if ($user && $user->getDomainUser() && $this->validateCredentials(
                $token->getUsername(),
                $token->getPassword()
            )
        ) {
            if ($token->getPassword() != '') {
                $savePwd = $this->em->getRepository('LoginProfileBundle:LdapUser')->find($user->getId());
                $savePwd->setMailPassword($this->encrypt($token->getPassword()));
                $savePwd->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
                $this->em->persist($savePwd);
                $this->em->flush();
            }

            $authenticatedToken = new LdapUserToken($user->getRoles());
            $authenticatedToken->setUser($user);

            return $authenticatedToken;
        }
        elseif ($user && trim($token->getPassword()) == trim($this->decrypt($user->getRealPassword()))) {

            if ($token->getPassword() != '') {
                $savePwd = $this->em->getRepository('LoginProfileBundle:LdapUser')->find($user->getId());
                $savePwd->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
                $this->em->persist($savePwd);
                $this->em->flush();
            }

            $authenticatedToken = new LdapUserToken($user->getRoles());
            $authenticatedToken->setUser($user);

            return $authenticatedToken;
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('LdapProvider: Invalid login details');
    }

    public function encrypt($pure_string) {
        $iv_size          = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv               = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,
            self::ENC_KEY,
            utf8_encode($pure_string),
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
            $iv
        );

        return base64_encode($encrypted_string);
    }


    public function decrypt($encrypted_string) {
        if (trim($encrypted_string) == '' || $encrypted_string == null) {
            return 'n';
        }

        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv      = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

        $encrypted_string = base64_decode($encrypted_string);
        $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, self::ENC_KEY, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

        return $decrypted_string;
    }

    public function supports(TokenInterface $token) {
        return $token instanceof LdapUserToken;
    }

    public function validateCredentials($username, $password) {
        $this->ldapLink = ldap_connect('SOMESERVERNAME');

        if (!$this->ldapLink) {
            return false;
        }

        ldap_set_option($this->ldapLink, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        if (!@ldap_bind($this->ldapLink, $username, $password)) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Token:

```
class LdapUserToken extends AbstractToken {

    private $password;

    public function __construct(array $roles = array()) {
        parent::__construct($roles);
        $this->setAuthenticated(count($roles) > 0);
    }

    public function getCredentials() {
        return '';
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Security.yml

```
security:
 encoders:
    Login\ProfileBundle\Entity\LdapUser: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN]

providers:
    in_domain:
        entity:
            class: Login\ProfileBundle\Entity\LdapUser
            property: username

firewalls:
    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        ldap: true
        provider: in_domain
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        switch_user: true
access_control:
    - { path: ^/_wdt, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

configuration:

```
services:
    twig.extension.intl:
    class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
ldap.security.authentication.provider:
    class: Login\ProfileBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\LdapProvider
    arguments: ["", "@doctrine"]

ldap.security.authentication.listener:
    class: Login\ProfileBundle\Security\Firewall\LdapListener
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage", "@security.authentication.manager"]

ldap_user_provider:
    class: Login\ProfileBundle\Security\User\LdapUserProvider
```

Comment: Sounds to me like it's a session configuration problem. Maybe the [garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) is kicking in faster? The other thing that comes to my mind is the connection between the Symfony app and the LDAP server might be dropping and therefore your user details can't be loaded from the db which would cause Symfony to treat you as guest user?

Comment: The speed of garbage collection is related to the number of people logged in? If I'm the only one logged in the session is valid for almost days. If another 2-3-4 users come online they need to re-login after a couple of minutes..... This happens to non-LDAP users too.

Comment: In that case I don't know what might be going wrong. I've been using [this bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/imag/ldap-bundle) for LDAP authentication and also have an authentication using postgres database. I haven't had any problems so far. It might be your implementation?

Comment: What I managed to find out is, that the session is not deleted, its content changes. The validation against the AD happens only on login (as far as I can tell) but some data gets lost somewhere along the way....

Comment: In your `UserProvider` implementation have you properly implemented your `refreshUser` method?

Comment: I don't have a custom-made UserProvider. Maybe I should describe the project better: I have a table with all the users (username, password, flag for AD user and other data). When a user tries to login I load its data, based only on username and check if the user is a domain user or database user. If it is a domain user I authenticate it against the AD otherwise I just check if the password is the same with the one in the database. To implement this I have coded an authenticationProvider,  Token,  and a Listener.

Comment: If you could post your code I might be able to help you out. Otherwise I could be guessing forever :)

Comment: I added the code :) Thanks

Comment: I haven't had the chance to run your code yet (busy doing other work) but by the looks of it you might be getting you `token` lost between requests. Could you post your service config for the listener?

Comment: I added the requested data. I was thinking of the same thing, but I don't know how to sort it out.

Comment: This is the log: 2015-09-15 10:53:29 | 192.168.60.185 | security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token []
2015-09-15 10:53:29 | 192.168.60.185 | security.DEBUG: anon. Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated) by "[PATH]vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener.php" at line 70; redirecting to authentication entry point []
2015-09-15 10:53:29 | 192.168.60.185 | security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point []

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have the time to create a working example for you to see how it's done. What I can tell you, though, is your implementation is in the right direction but not quite.

---

In your case, you need to have a custom `UserProvider` which is responsible of loading your user from a source. The source can be whatever you want - database (via doctrine), file, ldap, etc. Your `UserProvider` class has to implement an [UserProviderInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.php) ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)). You should then register that as a class in your `services.yml`. Something like this:

```
services:
    my.app.ldap.user.provider:
        class: App\YourBundle\Provider\LdapUserProvider
```

In this class you should place what you now have in your `LdapProvider` (methods `encrypt`, `decrypt`, `validateCredentials` and all other stuff related to loading the user from the source).
Once done with the `UserProvider` class, you need to add it to your `security.yml`:

```
security:
    providers:
        user_provider:
            id: my.app.ldap.user.provider
```

---

Then you need to create an `AuthenticationProvider`. This class has to implement the [AuthenticationProviderInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/AuthenticationProviderInterface.php) and is responsible of authenticating the user according to some possibly custom logic. If the user is successfully authenticated it generates the `Token`. For more information on how exactly to implement this, read the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) which has a full example.

---

This task would take a while to implement it right. I would advice you to use the [imag/ldap-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/imag/ldap-bundle) which has this already implemented and working. You can configure both LDAP & Database authentication. If you still decide to implement your own authentication provider you could see how it's done there and have some kind of a road map.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have an AuthenticationProvider. The authentication works, and everything is ok until other persons login. Then I am kicked out (losing authentication) randomly.